# Titanium mobile multiple select

Tags: html, forms, titanium-mobile

I can not find a library or module anywhere that implements a simple multiple select popup. I want something exactly like what comes up after touching an option/select dialog on a web-page.

Is there any way to get a web page's option/select to pop up without the page. Maybe a hidden page could be created, and the option dialog automatically selected, triggering it to pop up.

Is it possible to do this? How would it look on iOS? I only have android to test on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two ways implementing this. A special module is not required:

- First you can use a [Ti.UI.Picker](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Picker) which is useful for a small set of choices. This will look like a date picker which is rather similar on iOS and Android. You can find examples in [documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Picker). **Update**: It seems, that it's not possible to use checkmarks in titanium though this is supported on native iOS.
- Alternatively you can use a [table view](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableView) (list) within a modal or popover (ios only) window or a separate view (which is better for android). This is useful for a large set of choices, because you are able to provide a search bar. Selection will be triggered by setting `hasCheckmark: true` on a [table view row](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableViewRow). (for better ui, use updateRow method on table view and use animation)

  This is part of an implementation for the second solution

  ```
  var self = Ti.UI.createWindow(...);

  var options = [/*array with all options*/ {title: 'Option 1', value: 1}, {title: 'Option 2', value: 2}];
  var selectedOptions = [0]; // array to store selected options, also pass preselected options

  var tableView = Ti.UI.createTableView({...});
  // add rows
  var i = 0, rows = [];
  options.forEach(function(option) {
    var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({hasCheck: selectedOptions.indexOf(i)!==-1, title: option.title });
    rows.push(row);
  });
  tableView.setData(rows);

  tableView.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var state = e.rowData.hasCheck;
    // reuse existing row (using its configuration, not its instance)
    var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow(e.rowData);
    row.hasCheck = !e.rowData.hasCheck;
    // or create a really new one
    var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
      //config here,
      hasCheck: !e.rowData.hasCheck,
    );
    tableView.updateRow(e.index, row, {animated: true});
    if (state) {
      selectedOptions.push(e.index
    } else {
      selectedOptions.splice(selectedOptions.indexOf(e.index),1);
  });

  self.open({modal: true});
  ```

Multiple Selection is possible in both cases. You should provide a DONE button in both cases to finish work.

Comment: Well, I tried your first suggestion, and found that on android (not sure about iOS) it only allows you to pick one item, like radio buttons. This would be perfect for me if it had checkboxes instead. Do you know of any way to enable checkboxes instead?

Comment: The second suggestion looks like it will work, thanks for the links, I did not know you could add system checkmarks to rows. Do you have any sample code, it sounds from your description like you have got a thorough implementation at your fingertips.

Comment: Hi, i updated my answer and added the important part for visually selecting multiple options. Futhermore you need a small array which contains all the selected items that is returned when the user presses the done button. Simply put this table view in a popover or modal window or a separate view or window on android.

Comment: i extended this solution a bit so you see the controlling logic.

Comment: Thanks for this, I used it, works great. (Although I actually ended up using `.rightImage` so I could make the style match my custom radio buttons too - but this definitely got me on the right track). I dropped you a bounty for the efforts.